# Nextjs API hangs when attach a file to the request body

Tags: api, rest, file-upload, next.js, multipartform-data

I have a nextjs application, I've implemented an api endpoint under the path

```
src/pages/api/[[...media]].ts
```

the configuration for this api endpoint is as follow

```js
export const config = {
  api: {
    // Enable `externalResolver` option in Next.js
    externalResolver: true,
    bodyParser: false,
    responseLimit: false
  }
};
```

My handler is just a test print

```
export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  console.log(`OK`);
 ....
```

If do a `POST` request with a `Multipart form-data` attached to the request and the **file is small it works**, otherwise **if the file is more than 1MB (that is the default limit on nextjs) the POST request hungs**.

I assumed that the config `bodyParser: false` disabled the automatic body parser and also the limit https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/request-helpers